# How to show the number in a text file and number plus one?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am a newbie of windows batch 
I would like to write batch to generate a series of log file.
sorry my poor english. 
let me try to explain what i want.

I have 5 Variables.

1. Period
2. Symbol
3. Start Year
4. End Year
5. Setting

I stored all variable into a text file.

```
Period.txt
----------

15min 30min

Symbol.txt
----------

AAA BBB CCC

StartYear.txt
-------------

2012 2013 2014 2015 2016

EndYear.txt (Actually the End Year is Start Year +1 )
-----------------------------------------------------

2013 2014 2015 2016 2017

Setting.txt
-----------

Setting1 Setting2 Setting3 Setting4 Setting5
```

I would like to generate a list of file XXX.log 
named `Setting_StartYear_EndYear_Max_period_Symbol.log`

For example:

```
Setting1_2012_2013_Max__15min_AAA.log    Setting1_2012_2013_Max__15min_BBB.log    Setting1_2012_2013_Max__15min_CCC.log    Setting1_2012_2013_Max__30min_AAA.log    Setting1_2012_2013_Max__30min_BBB.log    Setting1_2012_2013_Max__30min_CCC.log
```

### And each of the log file will show this content.

```
; Tested settings Report
Tested Period=15min
Tested Symbol=AAA
Tested Start Year=2012
Tested End Year=2013
Tested Setting=Setting2
; End settings Report
```

I wrote a batch file called **gen.bat**

```
@echo off
SET output_filename=%%E_%%C_%%D_Max_%Symbol%_%%A_%%B
SET BaseDir=%cd%
For /f "delims=" %%E in (%BaseDir%\Setting.txt) do (
For /f "delims=" %%D in (%BaseDir%\EndYear.txt) do (
For /f "delims=" %%C in (%BaseDir%\StartYear.txt) do (
For /f "delims=" %%B in (%BaseDir%\Symbol.txt) do (
For /f "delims=" %%A in (%BaseDir%\Period.txt) do (
REM --------GEN Then log file-----------
Echo.; Tested settings Report>%output_filename%.log
Echo.Tested Period=%%A>>%output_filename%.log
Echo.Tested Symbol=%%B>>%output_filename%.log
Echo.Tested Start Year=%%C>>%output_filename%.log
Echo.Tested End Year=%%D>>%output_filename%.log
Echo.Tested Setting=%%E>>%output_filename%.log
Echo.; End settings Report>>%output_filename%.log
)))))
```

the result is, it is generating a lot of files with **wrong** start and end year like this

```
Setting1_2012_2012_Max__15min_AAA.log << Wrong
Setting1_2012_2012_Max__15min_BBB.log << Wrong
Setting1_2012_2012_Max__15min_CCC.log << Wrong
Setting1_2012_2012_Max__30min_AAA.log << Wrong
Setting1_2012_2012_Max__30min_BBB.log << Wrong
Setting1_2012_2012_Max__30min_CCC.log << Wrong
Setting1_2012_2013_Max__15min_AAA.log << Correct (as end year must be next year of start year )
Setting1_2012_2013_Max__15min_BBB.log << Correct (as end year must be next year of start year )
Setting1_2012_2013_Max__15min_CCC.log << Correct (as end year must be next year of start year )
Setting1_2012_2013_Max__30min_AAA.log << Correct (as end year must be next year of start year )
Setting1_2012_2013_Max__30min_BBB.log << Correct (as end year must be next year of start year )
Setting1_2012_2013_Max__30min_CCC.log << Correct (as end year must be next year of start year )
Setting1_2012_2014_Max__15min_AAA.log << Wrong
Setting1_2012_2014_Max__15min_BBB.log << Wrong
Setting1_2012_2014_Max__15min_CCC.log << Wrong
Setting1_2012_2014_Max__30min_AAA.log << Wrong
```

Could anyone could help me to fine tune my script?

I had tried with a few days but don't know how to correct the batch.

Comment: It will not work as you think. besides the incorrect filenames you get now, there will be cases where startyear will be 2016 and end year 2014 etc. This is because you do not set limits. Also, look at using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

Comment: thanks your for reply , so what should I modified it , so that it can run as my thought ?

Comment: See answer as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of setting `Start Year + 1` using `set /a`

Also see how setlocal delayedexpansion is used in the below example by using `!` instead of `%` for more on that, from cmdline run `setlocal /?`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For /f "delims=" %%C in (%BaseDir%\StartYear.txt) do (
set /a Sdate=%%C
for %%i in (!Sdate!) do set /a Edate=%%i+1
echo !Edate!
)
```

Which by using examples in **StartYear.txt** will add +1 to each:

```
2012  --> 2013
2013  --> 2014
2014  --> 2015
2015  --> 2016
2016  --> 2017
..etc..
```